# It's this a bug in rails? about single table inheritance;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

---

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Sub < Parent
end

class SubSub < Sub
end
```

---

```
>> SubSub.create :name => 'name1'
>> SubSub.create :name => 'name2'
>> SubSub.create :name => 'name3'
```

---

Then

---

```
>> SubSub.all.map{|x| x.name}    # => ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
>> Sub.all.map {|x| x.name}      # => []  # I was expected that it will show all items;
>> Parent.all.map { |x| x.name}  # => ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
```

---

I need Sub.all to show all its subclass's items, how to make it? It's this a bug?

---

I tested again, and it did work when there is no 'type' column specified in the table, but fails when with the 'type' column.

---

There is just one table named 'parents' with 'type' column;

---

My Env: rails-3.0.0.beta3, ruby-1.9.2-pre

Answer (score 0):

Sub.all DOES show all its subclass' items. I suggest you check your code. DEFINITELY not a bug.

Comment: Thanks, I test again, and it did work when there is no 'type' column specified in the table, but fails when with the 'type' column.

Comment: You have to have the 'type ' column. Otherwise Rails will not be able to exhibit STI behavior.

Comment: By any chance you havent created tables for Sub and Subsub , have you?

Comment: Nope, just one table named 'parents' with type field, but could I create multi tables for STI ?

Comment: No, you shouldn't create multiple tables. Just one table.